# Java query find only the first entry

Tags: java

If I try the following query in Java, Java returns without any error only the first entry of the table. But if I copy the same query to Access, Access returns all 33 entries.

Query:

`SELECT Country, Sum(SumOfNumber) AS number FROM CountryList WHERE Year=2012 AND (Month=1 Or Month=2 Or Month=3) AND Entity='xxx' GROUP BY Country ORDER BY Sum(SumOfNumber) DESC`

```
rs.last();
System.out.println(rs.getRow());
```

returns 1.

Any advice?

Okay guys, now I deleted therm "ORDER BY Sum(SumOfNumber) DESC" and Java returned all Countries and throwed an exception at the end "invalid cursor status"

```
public void doconnect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectURL,user,pw);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);


        String query = "SELECT Country, Sum(SumOfNumbers) AS number FROM CountryList WHERE Year=2012 AND (Month=1 Or Month=2 Or Month=3) AND Entity='xxx' GROUP BY Country ORDER BY Sum(SumOfNumbers) DESC";
        System.out.println(query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString("Country"));
        }
        rs.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(conn!=null){
            try{
                conn.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code please?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
rs.last();
System.out.println(rs.getRow());
```

to (to get all countries)

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString("Country"));
}
```

to get results from all rows instead of just the last one.

Comment: Yes I know that. I jump to the last row to get the number of the last row. So because the last row has the number "1", the whole table has only one 1 row. But that can't be true.

Comment: @user1688612: The implementation of `getRow()` is optional for some `ResultSet`s, have you confirmed that the data isn't there?

Comment: The data must be there, because exactly the same query gives me back 33 entries in access. And it's also not the first time I am doing this. This is the first time that this happened, and I cannot explain what I did wrong or different.

Answer (score 0):

From java API  resultSet.last()
          **Moves the cursor to the last row in this ResultSet object.**
[Check it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last%28%29),
remove rs.last and iterating over resultset like this

```
 while(rs.next()) {
    sysout(rs.getString("your column name"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get only one row (the last one). This is because you go directly to the last row of the ResultSet using `rs.last()`. Try to iterate over the ResultSet in order to get all rows returned.

To see how many rows are returned you can run query : `SELECT count(*) as count FROM CountryList WHERE Year=2012 AND (Month=1 Or Month=2 Or Month=3) AND Entity='xxx'` and then get the count using

```
while(rs.next()){
  int count = rs.getInt("count");
}
```

Comment: what kind of exception do you get?

Comment: something like invalid cursor status.

Comment: I guess the problem is the jdbc-odbc bridge

Answer (score 0):

`rs.last()` moves the cursor to the last row in the `resultSet` which means that after you've read the line, no more data is available, i also suggest that you use the function provided by

> Keppil: while (rs.next()) {
>       System.out.println(rs.getRow()); }

Comment: Only to show you that I know what I am doing here.
while(rs.next()){
rs.getRow();
}
returns also 1!